# Logging to a file in tabular format

Tags: shell-script, scripting, logs, printf

I am trying to `print` something into a file through the script which will be sent as an attachment to the mail.

Now what i am willing is to preserve a proper formatting within the file.
Can i print maintaining the tabular format similar to something what we do it html tables.

Suppose, in a loop the code is appending something like:

```
       `print "|App Name:$1\tRegion:$2\tEnvironment:$3| >> file_attch.dat`
```

Now the argument size can vary, say $1 can be 7-10 character , $2 is 5-15 character and $3 is 10-20 character.Now printing successive line of varying character length is making the attachment look odd.

Can i do something to reserve first 10 character for $1, 15 characters for $2 ad say 20 character for $3. Kind of formatting within `print` which would server the purpose.

**UPDATE**:

MAy be i didnt framed the question properly. Here is a example :

```
    App:PROPIA  Region:silo2   Env:INT
    App:SRO  Region:silo3   Env:SYS
```

In the above case as PROPIA and SRO vary with character length, the tabular format is not preserved. I wanted something like below:

```
    App:PROPIA  Region:silo2   Env:INT
    App:SRO     Region:silo3   Env:SYS
```

Something like reserving 10 character for 1st argument and next 10 for 2nd argument, irrespective of the ;ength of actual character

Comment: Are you sure, the `column` tool will not do what you need?

Comment: I have not used column tool yet. Can you give a good example to do this using column. At the same time il have a look at manual even

Comment: @Alex ,Column tool is not able to preserve the spacing, its working like tab formatting.   
 App:PROPIA   Region:silo2   Env:INT

Comment: Try `column -t -s ' ' file_attach.dat > file_attach.formated.dat` after the loop . Or try with `mount` vs. `mount | column -t -s ' '` . From your question I understand this to be the formatting wanted by you. Isn't it?

Comment: i edited my question with update section, @cas, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'App:%-10s\tRegion:%-15s\tEnv:%-20s\n' "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

This would reserve 10, 15, and 20 characters for the three strings and would also left-justify the strings within that space.

Example script:

```
set -- PROPIA silo2 INT SRO silo3 SYS
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
    printf 'App:%-10s\tRegion:%-15s\tEnv:%-20s\n' "$1" "$2" "$3"
    shift 3
done
```

Output:

```
App:PROPIA      Region:silo2            Env:INT
App:SRO         Region:silo3            Env:SYS
```